# Restrict create action in CrudRepository, only allow edit action

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using Spring Boot spring-data-rest to create CrudRepository, and expose rest endpoints to user.

But I want to prevent user from creating new record.
Just allow user to update existed record only.

How can it be achieved? CrudRepository doesn't have `create` method, just `save` `delete`...

Comment: Judging from your comment below you did not ask the actual question you had. Can you update your question to match your actual problem and post your solution as an answer so it might help others with a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CrudRepository provides `CREATE` and `EDIT` in same method `save`.
But spring-data-rest exposes these 2 operations, by HTTP method POST, PUT, PATCH.

POST is used for `CREATE`, so we can restrict this method by spring-security: antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/...").denyAll()

I create example project [here](https://github.com/akivamu/spring-data-rest-security-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an interceptor:

```
public class SecurityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        // insert logic here to check if it's an update
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);

    }

}
```

Add the interceptor with your application.yaml :

```
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ejb:
          interceptor: hello.SecurityInterceptor
```

Comment: I found the method to restrict HTTP POST, using `antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/...").denyAll()`. But thank you for the answer.